# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of A bytes exhausted (tried to allocate B bytes). Never happened before installing VM on CentOS with LAMP

Tags: magento-1.8

I have installed Xammp and Magento CE  1.8 on windows 8.
I have been following the same tutorial once in a while for a year: developping a module with a simple Model. It worked fine. But now,adding a connection to the database resource causes the fatal error mentionned in the title.

Fine tuning php.ini does not solve the problem. Reinstalling everything (xammp and native Magento neither).

I am wondering why the fatal error never happened with the exact same code for 30 or so times in a year, and does always now. The only new thing on my computer is an Oracle VM running CentOs and LAMP.

Although I get the fatal error, even though VM is not launched, I am left with only one possible explaination: the VM (even off) has something to do with this.

Comment: Are you sure your PHP gets as much memory as you are setting him? If you are running the code inside VM then not only PHP settings come in play but also the VM itself might not get enough. Typically when running a PHP script like magetno you need to include memory for PHP, nginx/apache, mysql. If you are additionally using maybe also varnish, redis and/or memcache. Make sure that exhausted limit is what PHP settings are set to (ie. with printing phpinfo())

Comment: Edit: This happens when running Xampp on windows and with VM off. I use default settings of Xampp. It did work for one year with these settings prior to installing Oracle VM.

Comment: Edit: Looks like I used a too recent version of xammp. mysql_error log said some things were deprecated (I did not save the log).

Comment: Then I downloaded xampp V3.1.0 which is older. But I still get the same issue (see aove) and odd messages in mysql_error log:

Comment: these:
170628 19:46:05 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170628 19:46:05 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170628 19:46:05 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
...(too many characters).
php.ini seems configured OK.

How should I configure my.ini or which version of xampp should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

Error was found:  my class was extending

```
Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

Instead of

```
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
```